# CNN accuracy and loss doesn't change over epochs for sentiment analysis

Tags: cnn, word2vec, accuracy, sentiment-analysis, gpu

I am performing text classification as **Good** [1] or **Bad** [0]. The texts are preprocessed and converted to Vectors using **Google Word2Vec**. Further **CNN** architecture is used for training. I have roughly **13000** texts as **Bad[0]** and **5450** texts as **Good[1]** for training (making it a roughly **70:30%**)
The issue starts when I realize I don't have enough compute power (2GB GPU). Hence I compromise and use **100 dimensions** of word embeddings from Word2Vec (instead of the 300). After certain hyperparameter tuning in the CNN architecture, I am able to obtain a **30-35% precision**, which I am happy with.
After months, I have an 8GB GPU in the server and I implemented the **300-dimensional** word embeddings in Word2Vec and kept for training. Ideally, I should have obtained better results; instead, the **loss and accuracy don't change with time for every epoch**. Thus it predicts all texts as Bad[0]. 
Can you please help me identify the problem and If I am missing out anything here!

**EDIT:**

I would like to add some **clarifications**:
In the **Linux server with GPU 1070Ti 8GB**, I tried with **three** experiments in this order: **a) 300-dimensional** word embeddings **b) 100-dimensional** word-embeddings and **c) 105-dimensional** word embeddings
I have obtained **no change in accuracy and loss for a) and c)**. However, for **b), it is exactly the same results** as I obtained with my **local GPU(750Ti Nvidia 2GB)**. In short, its working fine for 100-dimensional in the server.

Now, since I **can't assign 300d word vectors in my local GPU**, I make up the same experiment as **c) with 105d vectors in the local GPU** to just check if there's any fault in code, and surprisingly it's giving around 30% precision much similar to earlier results.

I am having a hard time figuring out the issue in the server GPU as its working fine for 100d word vectors but fail to give proper predictions for other dimensional word-embeddings.

I am attaching some results which might make it a lot clear:

1.) Trained with **100d vectors in local(2GB) GPU**
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
    0.0       0.70      0.83      0.76      1973
    1.0       **0.31**      0.17      0.22       850
```

avg / total       0.58      0.63      0.60      2823

2.)  Trained with **100d vectors in server (8GB) GPU**
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
    0.0       0.70      0.77      0.73      1973
    1.0       **0.30**      0.23      0.26       850
```

avg / total       0.58      0.61      0.59      2823

3.) This is the same result for both **105d and 300d vectors** trained in **server GPU**
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
    0.0       0.70      1.00      0.82      1973
    1.0       **0.00**      0.00      0.00       850
```

avg / total       0.49      0.70      0.58      2823

4.) Trained with **105d vectors in local(2GB) GPU**
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
    0.0       0.70      0.83      0.76      1973
    1.0       **0.30**      0.18      0.23       850
```

avg / total       0.57      0.64      0.61      2823

Answer (score 2):

You have imbalanced Data, that's why your network always predicts the most frequent answer (he is in a local minima).

There are solutions to avoid this kind of problem:

- Balance your data, use as much "good" as "bad" in your training set.
- Change your cost function,  e.g. the cost of error on "good" should be higher than "bad".

(don't use both at the same times or your model will be imbalanced in the other class)

If you look for imbalanced data on google you will find lot of articles on this problem, since it is common.